# How to color 10 similar objects with$ 3$ colors?

Tags: combinatorics

We are given $10$ similar objects and we are going to color them. $3$ of them using black color, $3$ of them using red color and $4$ of them using white color. in how many ways we can do this?

---

If they were distinct in $C(10,3) \times C(7,3) \times C(4,4)$ ways we could color them. but because they are similar I guess there is only 1 way to color them because no difference does it make which object is selected. but it is not the correct answer. the answer is

$\displaystyle {1\over 10} \times {10! \over  4!3!3!}$

and I don't know how to get this answer!

Comment: I feel like your reasoning is correct. Maybe the objects aren't exactly identical? Is there any more information about what similarity means here?

Comment: No there is no more information!

Comment: go to this book http://www.scribd.com/doc/24696606/Discrete-and-rial-Mathematics-An-Applied-Introduction-5th-Ed-R-Grimaldi-Pearson-2004-WW#scribd page 43 of the book (or page 64 OF 1005 in the website page indicator)

Answer (score 2):

I also think it's one. I don't know how it could be different than one. I truly think the answer is incorrect or the question is not well formulated.

Comment: go to this book http://www.scribd.com/doc/24696606/Discrete-and-rial-Mathematics-An-Applied-Introduction-5th-Ed-R-Grimaldi-Pearson-2004-WW#scribd page 43 of the book (or page 64 OF 1005 in the website page indicator)